# How do I pass value to a stored procedure parameter in OLE DB Source component?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am working with SSIS 2008. I have a select query name *`sqlquery1`* that returns some rows:

```
aq
dr
tb
```

This query is not implemented on the SSIS at the moment.

I am calling a stored procedure from an OLE DB Source within a Data Flow Task. I would like to pass the data obtained from the query to the stored procedure parameter.

#### Example:

I would like to call the stored procedure by passing the first value *`aq`*

```
storedProdecure1 'aq'
```

then pass the second value *`dr`*

```
storedProdecure1 'dr'
```

I guess it would be something like a cycle. I need this because the data generated by the *`OLE DB Source`* through the stored procedure needs to be sent to another destination and this must be done for each record of the *sqlquery1*.

I would like to know how to call the query *`sqlquery1`* and pass its output to call another stored procedure.

How do I need to do this in SSIS?

Comment: You have a query that returns the above dataset. I'm not sure how that factors in with the stored procedure you'd like to use in your OLE DB Source. Could you update your question? Even if it's just psuedo-code, I think that'd help use understand your problem.

Comment: i just edited the question. but the basic point is that I would like the stored procedure to take the value from the first row of the dataset(aq), then it would take the second one(dr) and so on

Comment: Is the intended behaviour that the `Data Flow` fires N times for each value in the original query or should the enumeration happen on the `OLE DB Source` The implications is based on your destination. If it's calling the data flow N times, then you'd need to ensure a flat file destination appends instead of overwrites.

Comment: Excellent, that's the easier version to answer. ;)

Comment: The Data Flow fires N times for each value in the original query, but everytime it fires it should write to a new excel file everytime

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Conceptually, what your solution will look like is an execute your source query to generate your result set. Store that into a variable and then you'll need to do iterate through those results and for each row, you'll want to call your stored procedure with that row's value and send the results into a new Excel file.

I'd envision your package looking something like this

An Execute SQL Task, named "SQL Load Recordset", attached to a Foreach Loop Container, named "FELC Shred Recordset". Nested inside there I have a File System Task, named "FST Copy Template" which is a precedence for a Data Flow Task, named "DFT Generate Output".

[image: Control Flow]

## Set up

As you're a beginner, I'm going to try and explain in detail. To save yourself some hassle, grab a copy of [BIDSHelper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com). It's a free, open source tool that improves the design experience in BIDS/SSDT.

### Variables

Click on the background of your Control Flow. With nothing selected, right-click and select Variables. In the new window that pops up, click the button that creates a New Variable 4 times. The reason for clicking on nothing is that until SQL Server 2012, the default behaviour of variable creation is to create them at the scope of the current object. This has resulted in many lost hairs for new and experienced developers alike. Variable names are case sensitive so be aware of that as well.

1. Rename Variable to RecordSet. Change the Data type from Int32 to Object
2. Rename Variable1 to ParameterValue. Change the data type from Int32 to String
3. Rename Variable2 to TemplateFile. Change the data type from Int32 to String. Set the value to the path of your output Excel File. I used C:\ssisdata\ShredRecordset.xlsx
4. Rename Variable 4 to OutputFileName. Change the data type from Int32 to String. Here we're going to do something slightly advanced. Click on the variable and hit F4 to bring up the Properties window. Change the value of EvaluateAsExpression to True. In Expression, set it to `"C:\\ssisdata\\ShredRecordset." + @[User::ParameterValue]  + ".xlsx"` (or whatever your file and path are). What this does, is configures a variable to change as the value of ParameterValue changes. This helps ensure we get a unique file name. You're welcome to change naming convention as needed. Note that you need to escape the `\` any time you are in an expression.

### Connection Managers

I have made the assumption you are using an OLE DB connection manager. Mine is named FOO. If you are using ADO.NET the concepts will be similar but there will be nuances pertaining to parameters and such.

You will also need a second Connection Manager to handle Excel. If SSIS is temperamental about data types, Excel is flat out psychotic-stab-you-in-the-back-with-a-fork-while-you're-sleeping about data types. We're going to wait and let the data flow actually create this Connection Manager to ensure our types are good.

## Source Query to Result Set

The `SQL Load Recordset` is an instance of the [Execute SQL Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx). Here I have a simple query to mimic your source.

```
SELECT 'aq' AS parameterValue
UNION ALL SELECT 'dr'
UNION ALL SELECT 'tb'
```

[image: execute sql task general tab]

What's important to note on the General tab is that I have switched my ResultSet from `None` to `Full result set`. Doing this makes the Result Set tab go from being greyed out to usable.

[image: execute sql task result set tab]
You can observe that I have assigned the Variable Name to the variable we created above (User::RecordSet) and I the Result Name is `0`. That is important as the default value, `NewResultName` doesn't work.

## FELC Shred Recordset

Grab a [Foreach Loop Container](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141724.aspx) and we will use that to "shred" the results that were generated in the preceding step.

Configure the enumerator as a `Foreach ADO Enumerator` Use `User::RecordSet` as your ADO object source variable. Select `rows in the first table` as your Enumeration mode

[image: Use the Foreach ADO Enumerator and use User::RecordSet as your source. Select rows in first table]

On the Variable Mappings tab, you will need to select your variable `User::ParameterValue` and assign it the Index of 0. This will result in the zerotth element in your recordset object being assigned to the variable ParameterValue. It is important that you have data type agreement as SSIS won't do implicit conversions here.

[image: Assign User::ParameterValue as the 0th index on the Variable Mappings tab]

## FST Copy Template

This a [File System Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140185.aspx). We are going to copy our template Excel File so that we have a well named output file (has the parameter name in it). Configure it as

- IsDestinationPathVariable: True
- DestinationVarible: User::OutputFileName
- OverwriteDestination: True
- Operation: Copy File
- IsSourcePathVariable: True
- SourceVariable: User::TemplateFile

[image]

## DFT Generate Output

This is a [Data Flow Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140080.aspx). I'm assuming you're just dumping results straight to a file so we'll just need an [OLE DB Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx) and an [Excel Destination](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137643.aspx)

[image: basic data flow]

### OLEDB dbo_storedProcedure1

This is where your data is pulled from your source system with the parameter we shredded in the Control Flow. I am going to write my query in here and use the `?` to indicate it has a parameter.

Change your Data access mode to "SQL Command" and in the SQL command text that is available, put your query

```
EXECUTE dbo.storedProcedure1 ?
```

[image: OLEDB Source to Excel Destination]

I click the Parameters... button and fill it out as shown

- Parameters: @parameterValue
- Variables: User::ParameterValue
- Param direction: Input

[image: Parameters configuration]

Connect an Excel Destination to the OLE DB Source. Double click and in the Excel Connection Manager section, click New... Determine if you're needing 2003 or 2007 format (.xls vs .xlsx) and whether you want your file to have header rows. For you File Path, put in the same value you used for your @User::TemplatePath variable and click OK.

[image: Excel Connection Manager]

We now need to populate the name of the Excel Sheet. Click that New... button and it may bark that there is not sufficient information about mapping data types. Don't worry, that's semi-standard. It will then pop up a table definition something like

```
CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination` (
    `name` NVARCHAR(35),
    `number` INT,
    `type` NVARCHAR(3),
    `low` INT,
    `high` INT,
    `status` INT
)
```

The "table" name is going to be the worksheet name, or precisely, the named data set in the worksheet. I made mine Sheet1 and clicked OK. Now that the sheet exists, select it in the drop down. I went with the Sheet1$ as the target sheet name. Not sure if it makes a difference.

[image: Excel Destination Editor]

Click the Mappings tab and things should auto-map just fine so click OK.

## Finally

At this point, if we ran the package it would overwrite the template file every time. The secret is we need to tell that `Excel Connection Manager` we just made that it needs to not have a hard coded name.

Click once on the Excel Connection Manager in the Connection Managers tab. In the Properties window, find the `Expressions` section and click the ellipses `...` Here we will configure the Property `ExcelFilePath` and the Expression we will use is 
`@[User::OutputFileName]`

If your icons and such look different, that's to be expected. This was documented using SSIS 2012. Your work flow will be the same in 2005 and 2008/2008R2 just the skin is different.

If you run this package and it doesn't even start and there is an error about the ACE 12 or Jet 4.0 something not available, then you are on a 64bit machine and need to tell BIDS/SSDT that you want to run in 32 bit mode.

Ensure the Run64BitRuntime value is `False`. This project setting can be found by right clicking on the project, expand the Configuration Properties and it will be an option under Debugging.

[image: 32bit property setting]

## Further reading

A different example of shredding a recordset object can be found on [How to automate the execution of a stored procedure with an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143386/how-to-automate-the-execution-of-a-stored-procedure-with-an-ssis-package/)

Comment: the foreach loop container is reached on execution, but the elements which are inside the loop are not. In this case the File System Task and the Data Flow Task are never executed.. What is causing this?

Comment: @pyram If the contents of the Foreach loop are not going green, then there is no data in your dataset (or you're not parsing it properly). Ensure you are have changed the enumerator type from the default file enumerator to one of type Foreach ADO Enumerator

Comment: i got lost here. This is on the Foreach loop properties?

Comment: Yeah, look at the "FELC Shred Recordset" Does your enumerator look like that?

Comment: When running the package i got error: "The file already exists". It seems the dynamic names are not working.. How can I solve this?

Comment: That is most likely the File System Task failing. Have you configured it as the screen shot shows? There is an option to `OvewriteDestination` which is set to True.

Comment: If I set OvewriteDestination to true the package executes without errors. But when checking the output path there is only one file. This means the package is overwriting file by file. When in fact there should be about 20 files there.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is this variable: ParameterValue...... On the steps you posted, I don't see where the ParameterValue is assigned a value.... I mean how ParameterValue takes its corresponding value?

Comment: That's good. That indicates the problem lies with either the expression to generate the file name or the expression on the Excel Connection Manager that uses the file name. If you would, put a screen shot of the properties window of the Excel Connection Manager and the variable itself so that we can all see what the hang up is. The other option, is to set a break point on the File System Task. Once that breakpoint is hit, under the Debug menu, select Windows, Locals. Expand Variables and look for the User::OutputFileName. The value there should have the shredded element in it

Comment: ParameterValue is being assigned to in the Foreach Loop

Comment: "ParameterValue is being assigned to in the Foreach Loop"...Where? on the Variable Mappings?...........By the way if you posted screen shots I cant see them :(.

Comment: Great answer, @billinkc, especially this line: _If SSIS is temperamental about data types, Excel is flat out psychotic-stab-you-in-the-back-with-a-fork-while-you're-sleeping about data types._