# ssis 2008, convert object to string on Expression Builder

Tags: ssis

im using SSIS for Sql server 2008.

Im declaring a path on a string variable on the Expression property:

```
"C:\\data\\Documents\\dt\\local." + @[User::Record] + ".xlsx"
```

The User::Record is of type Object.

I want to know how can I convert it from Object to String so I can assign it on the path.

Thanks..

Comment: You cannot do anything with an SSIS variable of type Object in an the expression editor. You need to slice out the zeroeth element of the @[User::Record] and assign it to @[User::ParameterValue] as noted in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961534/ssis-2008-pass-value-to-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression` is evaluated at `compile time` .So the variable User::Record is initialized as `System.Object type` .It does not contain any value .

Instead of declaring it as an expression ,try to use a `script task` to assign the path to the string variable .

```
Dts.Variables["User::Path"].Value =
"C:\\data\\Documents\\dt\\local." + Dts.Variables["User::Record"].Value.ToString() + ".xlsx"
```

I assume that before assigning the path to the string variable you are storing some value in User::Record variable .
Else even after the above script task code ,your path variable will hold the value

```
C:\data\Documents\dt\local.System.Object.xlsx
```