# SSIS convert object variable to string

Tags: variables, object, ssis

I would like to store a single row result set to a variable. To able to do this I have to set my variable TxtNotes to Object. The issue I'm having is using this TxtNotes variable to use with nother string variable. Something like:
EmailBody = "We have notes: " + "\n" + @[User::TxtNotes]
I have tried this article: [ssis 2008, convert object to string on Expression Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994310/ssis-2008-convert-object-to-string-on-expression-builder)
I keep getting this error: Error: 0xC0019001 at Script Task: The wrapper was unable to set the value of the variable specified in the ExecutionValueVariable property.
Help needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution:

```
Using CAST(txtnotes AS varchar(8000)) AS TxtNotes
```

in Execute SQL Task.