# ssis 2005, write on excel files

Tags: ssis

Im trying to do this:

[How do I pass value to a stored procedure parameter in OLE DB Source component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961534/ssis-2008-pass-value-to-query)

on SSIS 2005.

I got everything compiled fine, but when executing, the data is not going to the excel files which has the new date, instead of that it goes to the template excel files.

Is there something I need to change so it runs on SSIS 2005?

Thanks

Comment: Revisit the "Finally" section of @billinkc answer and pay close attention.  That is the part that tells the connection manager to use your new name for the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Beat me to it again @Siva

Comment: Yes. It's as you guys said. The finally part. Thanks.