# Can't pass in variables into OLE DB source command

Tags: ssis

I am creating a SSIS package that involves a where clause as:
WHERE effectiveDate >= @effectiveDate

Therefore, I defined `@effectiveDate` at the package level so that I can pass in value from a sql command using a different connection.

At the OLE DB source, I selected 'SQL command', and put the code as
Select ... FROM ...
WHERE effectiveDate >= ?

When I click on the 'parameters', an error appears:
'Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command. blablabla... use "SQL command from variable"...'

I am trying to avoid using SQL command from variable and try to locate the problem since I should be able to pass in variable.

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass value to a stored procedure parameter in OLE DB Source component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961534/how-do-i-pass-value-to-a-stored-procedure-parameter-in-ole-db-source-component)

Answer (score 0):

When building an [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should actually name the parameter as the package is expecting, such as

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( "select ... from... where... eff > @yourPkgPameterName");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@yourPkgPameterName", whateverValueToSend );
```

It's been a while for SQL-based parameters and don't remember if the AddWithValue() method is expecting the "@" or not... may need to try without it if it fails.

Comment: You answer is correct for C# but this question is about the SSIS execution environment which does not use the @ nomenclature for variables.

Comment: @billinkc, I guess that was your down-vote then... But the user then explicitly was referencing an OleDbCommand with select with ?,   So, which is it... the query to get data, or calling the report that is failing.. a newbie score of 3?  Not going to be the greatest in clarification.